# react-router, pass props with <Link>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

in component 1 I have two buttons that direct to component 2

```
<Link to="item" /*new item*/><button .../></Link>
<Link to="item" /*edit item*/><button .../></Link>
```

component 2 has 2 const that according to props should return one of the modes.

```
render(){
const editMode=(<div>....</div>)
const newMode=(<div>....</div>)
return(<div> ..... {this.props.editMode? editMode: newMode} </div>)}
```

how should I pass a boolean like `editMode:true or false` via Link ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [location descriptor](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/v2.x/docs/Location.md) as your `to` prop and pass the value using the state.

```
<Link to={{ state: { edit: true }}}>...</Link>
```

You can access that value through the [location prop](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#injected-props) injected into the route's component.